# How to speed up Visual Studio Webserver (Cassini)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, cassini

for my webapp the integrated Visual Studio Server (Cassini) ist much slower than IIS. How can I speed up Cassini so that i dont have to wait for 3s for every small page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you seeing this on a Web Application Project or a Website Project?

If it's a Website, then the issue just may be that the Development Server needs to compile each page the first time it's executed. Are subsequent requests of the same page faster?

If it's a Web Application Project then Visual Studio compiles it all before the Development Server runs it. In this case, are you sure it's the Development Server? Is there the same delay for EVERY page in the application?

Also, Are you sure it isn't disk or database latency?

Answer (score 2):

1. Determine why you think the web server is the culprit.
   How did you determine that it was the web server? How did you measure this 3 seconds? Is it on every page, or just certain pages? Is it continuous, or does it get better after a while?
2. Determine what aspect of the slow web server is the problem.
   Is there a lot of CPU in use? Memory? Are there other things happening when this happens? When you're using IIS, are you running on the same computer that had the slow Cassini? Is everything else the same? Same database server? Same hard disks in use?

You've got to narrow things down, as in any performance analysis.